# Rendering to different objects using different textures and different shaders

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm programming a voxel game. I have implented procedurally generated terrain. Now I want to program a map that should show on the upper right corner of the screen and that shows the biomes that are nearby. To do this my idea was to create a separate shader program, vbo, and vao, and a texture and that I would write to as the player moved around.
Is there a better way to do this?

Here I create the map:

```
GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    float vertices[] = {
        -.5f, -.5f, 0,  0, 0,
        -.5f, .5f, 0,   0, 1,
        .5f, .5f, 0,    1, 1,
        .5f, -.5f, 0,   1, 0
    };
    /*float vertices[] = {
        -1, -.5f, 0,
        0, .5f, 0,
        .5f, -.5f, 0
    };*/
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3
    };
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // 2. copy our vertices array in a vertex buffer for OpenGL to use
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // 3. copy our index array in a element buffer for OpenGL to use
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // 4. then set the vertex attributes pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GLuint tbo;
    int apothem = 256;
    unsigned char pixels[apothem*apothem*3];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < apothem*apothem*3; i++) {
        pixels[i] = 1;
        //std::cout << "changed pixels[" << i << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, apothem, apothem, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, 0, 0, apothem, apothem, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    // set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on the currently bound texture object)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And here's the rendering loop:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Poll and handle events (inputs, window resize, etc.)
        // You can read the io.WantCaptureMouse, io.WantCaptureKeyboard flags to tell if dear imgui wants to use your inputs.
        // - When io.WantCaptureMouse is true, do not dispatch mouse input data to your main application, or clear/overwrite your copy of the mouse data.
        // - When io.WantCaptureKeyboard is true, do not dispatch keyboard input data to your main application, or clear/overwrite your copy of the keyboard data.
        // Generally you may always pass all inputs to dear imgui, and hide them from your application based on those two flags.
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        static float scale[3] = {1, 1, 1};
        static float rotation[3] = {0, 0, 0};
        static float position[3] = {0, 0, 0};
        // 2. Show a simple window that we create ourselves. We use a Begin/End pair to create a named window.
        {
            ImGui::Begin("Chunk settings");                          // Create a window called "Hello, world!" and append into it.

            ImGui::SliderFloat3("scale", scale, -5, 5);
            ImGui::SliderFloat3("rotation", rotation, -360, 360);
            ImGui::SliderFloat3("position", position, -5, 5);
            ImGui::ColorEdit3("clear color", (float*)&clear_color); // Edit 3 floats representing a color

            ImGui::Text("Application average %.3f ms/frame (%.1f FPS)", 1000.0f / ImGui::GetIO().Framerate, ImGui::GetIO().Framerate);
            ImGui::End();
        }

        {
            int x = mainPlayer.GetPos().x(), z = mainPlayer.GetPos().z();
            ImGui::Begin("World settings");

            float continentalness = voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetContinentalness(x, z);
            ImGui::Text("Continentalness: %.4f, Continentalness degree: %d", continentalness,
            voxelEngine::mainWorld.ContinentalnessDegree(continentalness));

            float erosion = voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetErosion(x, z);
            ImGui::Text("Erosion: %.4f, Erosion Degree: %d", erosion,
            voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetErosionDegree(erosion));

            float humidity = voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetHumidity(x, z);
            ImGui::Text("Humidity: %.4f, Humidity Degree: %d", humidity,
            voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetHumidityDegree(humidity));

            float temperature = voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetTemperature(x, z);
            ImGui::Text("Temperature: %.4f, Temperature Degree: %d", temperature,
            voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetTemperatureDegree(temperature));

            float elevation = voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetElevation(x, z);
            ImGui::Text("Elevation: %.4f, Elevation Degree: %d", elevation,
            voxelEngine::mainWorld.GetElevationDegree(elevation));

            ImGui::End();
        }

        static float n = .3, f = .5, speed, sensitivity, fov, pitch, yaw;
        static Eigen::Vector3f cam_pos;
        speed = voxelEngine::players->GetSpeed();
        sensitivity = voxelEngine::players->GetSensitivity();
        fov = voxelEngine::players->GetFOV();
        pitch = voxelEngine::players->GetPitch();
        yaw = voxelEngine::players->GetYaw();
        cam_pos = voxelEngine::players->GetPos();
        {
            ImGui::Begin("Camera settings");
            ImGui::SliderFloat("cam x", &cam_pos.x(), -10, 10);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("cam y", &cam_pos.y(), -10, 10);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("cam z", &cam_pos.z(), -10, 10);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("speed", &speed, 0, 1);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("sensitivity", &sensitivity, 0, 1);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("fov", &fov, 0, 90);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("pitch", &pitch, -360, 360);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("yaw", &yaw, -360, 360);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("near plane", &n, 0, 1);
            ImGui::SliderFloat("far plane", &f, 0, 1);
            ImGui::ColorEdit3("clear color", (float*)&clear_color); // Edit 3 floats representing a color
            ImGui::End();
        }
        voxelEngine::players->SetPos(cam_pos);
        voxelEngine::players->SetSpeed(speed);
        voxelEngine::players->SetSensitivity(sensitivity);
        voxelEngine::players->SetFOV(fov);
        voxelEngine::players->SetDirection(pitch, yaw);

        // Rendering
        ImGui::Render();
        int display_w, display_h;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &display_w, &display_h);
        glViewport(0, 0, display_w, display_h);
        glClearColor(clear_color.x * clear_color.w, clear_color.y * clear_color.w, clear_color.z * clear_color.w, clear_color.w);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        float projMat[16];
        float viewMat[16];
        //float modelMat[16];
        /*voxelEngine::genModelMatrix({scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]}, {rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2]},
            {position[0],
            position[1],
            position[2]}, modelMat);*/
        voxelEngine::players->genViewMatrix(viewMat);
        voxelEngine::genProjMatrix(n, f, (float)display_h/display_w, voxelEngine::players->GetFOV(), projMat);
        //glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(voxelEngine::program, "modelMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, modelMat);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, blockTextures);
        glUseProgram(worldProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(worldProgram, "viewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, viewMat);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(worldProgram, "projMatrix"), 1, GL_TRUE, projMat);
        mainPlayer.Render();

        float mapProj[16];
        float mapModel[16];
        voxelEngine::genModelMatrix(Eigen::Vector3f(.7, .7, .7), Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 0), Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 1), mapModel);
        voxelEngine::genProjMatrix(n, f, (float)display_h/display_w, 90, mapProj);

        glUseProgram(guiProgram);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(guiProgram, "my_sampler"), 1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(guiProgram, "projMat"), 1, GL_TRUE, mapProj);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(guiProgram, "modelMat"), 1, GL_FALSE, mapModel);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        
        //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, apothem, apothem, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, 0, 0, apothem, apothem, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        /*voxelEngine::mainBiomeMap->Bind();
        voxelEngine::mainBiomeMap->Render();*/
        
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
        
        // Update and Render additional Platform Windows
        // (Platform functions may change the current OpenGL context, so we save/restore it to make it easier to paste this code elsewhere.
        //  For this specific demo app we could also call glfwMakeContextCurrent(window) directly)
        if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
        {
            GLFWwindow* backup_current_context = glfwGetCurrentContext();
            ImGui::UpdatePlatformWindows();
            ImGui::RenderPlatformWindowsDefault();
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(backup_current_context);
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
    }
```

Everything renders fine except the map which is just black.
This is where I render the map:

```
float mapProj[16];
        float mapModel[16];
        voxelEngine::genModelMatrix(Eigen::Vector3f(.7, .7, .7), Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 0), Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 1), mapModel);
        voxelEngine::genProjMatrix(n, f, (float)display_h/display_w, 90, mapProj);

        glUseProgram(guiProgram);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(guiProgram, "my_sampler"), 1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(guiProgram, "projMat"), 1, GL_TRUE, mapProj);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(guiProgram, "modelMat"), 1, GL_FALSE, mapModel);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        
        //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, apothem, apothem, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, 0, 0, apothem, apothem, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `unsigned char pixels[apothem*apothem*3];` You can't create an array like that. Apothem either needs to be a compile time constant or you need to allocate memory dynamically. 
`pixels[i] = 1`. You're setting every pixel to have an rgb value of 1, which is basically black. What were you expecting to get?

Comment: I changed it to a dynamically allocated array:

int apothem = 256;
    unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[apothem*apothem*3];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < apothem*apothem*3; i++) {
        pixels[i] = 1;
        //std::cout << "changed pixels[" << i << "]" << std::endl;
    }

It did not change anything.
And rgb(1, 1, 1, 1) is white btw.

Comment: RGB(1, 1, 1) is only white when the color is a float. Your texture is using GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE as the internal format, which is an 8 bit unsigned integer. 8 bit unsigned integers use colors in the range 0-255, rather than the 0-1 that floats use. Try setting `pixels[i]` to 255 and see if you get white.